# Calculation percentage of response from a survey table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table in which I store survey data. Each survey is if 5 questions. Users answer can be either 1 or 0 against each question and each survey has a date associated with it

I need to come up with a query so that I can get the %age of people answered '1' for each questions.

My example data:

```
RecId | AnswerdId | QuestionId | Answer | Date
----------------------------------------------------
1           1          1            1     6/1/2016
2           1          2            0     6/1
3           1          3            1     6/1
4           1          4            0     6/1
5           1          5            1     6/1
6           2          1            0     6/2
7           2          2            0     6/2
8           2          3            1     6/2
9           2          4            1     6/2
10          2          5            1     6/2
```

I need an output like

```
Question1   Question2 Question3  Question4  Question5
   50%          0%       100%       50%       100%
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (RecId int,AnswerID int,QuestionID int,Answer int,Date Date)
Insert into @Table (RecId,AnswerID,QuestionId,Answer,Date) values
(1,1,1, 1,'6/1/2016'),
(2,1,2, 0,'6/1/2016'),
(3,1,3, 1,'6/1/2016'),
(4,1,4, 0,'6/1/2016'),
(5,1,5, 1,'6/1/2016'),
(6,2,1, 0,'6/2/2016'),
(7,2,2, 0,'6/2/2016'),
(8,2,3, 1,'6/2/2016'),
(9,2,4, 1,'6/2/2016'),
(10,2,5, 1,'6/2/2016')

;with cteSum as (Select QuestionID,Pct = sum(Answer)/(count(*)+0.0) From @Table Group By QuestionID)
Select Question1 = format(sum(case when QuestionID=1 then Pct else 0 end),'0%')
      ,Question2 = format(sum(case when QuestionID=2 then Pct else 0 end),'0%')
      ,Question3 = format(sum(case when QuestionID=3 then Pct else 0 end),'0%')
      ,Question4 = format(sum(case when QuestionID=4 then Pct else 0 end),'0%')
      ,Question5 = format(sum(case when QuestionID=5 then Pct else 0 end),'0%')
 From cteSum
```

Returns

```
Question1   Question2   Question3   Question4   Question5
50%         0%          100%        50%         100%
```

Comment: I should add.  Question 3 is 100%, not 50% as displayed

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" is to use a `CASE` statement inside a `SUM` function, deciding there which answer values should be considered. In the example below, that `SELECT` its the innermost query and you can already compute the percentual.

As you want to show each value in a different *column*, you can also use the same approach suggested by @JohnCappelletti and compute each column separately, or you can `PIVOT` that result set. Be aware the answer values (represented as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc) can't be dynamically read without using dynamic SQL, ok?

I prefer to return all results as decimal because the presentation layer (not the data layer) should be responsible by formatting that value.

```
;WITH SurveyData    AS
(
    SELECT  RecId, AnswerdId, QuestionId, Answer
    FROM    (   VALUES 
                (01, 1, 1, 1),
                (02, 1, 2, 0),
                (03, 1, 3, 1),
                (04, 1, 4, 0),
                (05, 1, 5, 1),
                (06, 2, 1, 0),
                (07, 2, 2, 0),
                (08, 2, 3, 1),
                (09, 2, 4, 1),
                (10, 2, 5, 1)
            )   AS Sample(RecId, AnswerdId, QuestionId, Answer)
)
SELECT  ISNULL(SUM([1]), 0) [Question1],
        ISNULL(SUM([2]), 0) [Question2],
        ISNULL(SUM([3]), 0) [Question3],
        ISNULL(SUM([4]), 0) [Question4],
        ISNULL(SUM([5]), 0) [Question5]
FROM    (
        SELECT      QuestionId,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Answer = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) Yes,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Answer = 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) No ,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Answer = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(Answer) Perc
        FROM        SurveyData
        GROUP BY    QuestionId
        )           AS SourceTable
PIVOT
        (           SUM(Perc)
                    FOR QuestionId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
        )           AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I used a temp table #temprecordset instead of your table. So, please replace it when you are using your code. I used a while loop to loop from the smallest to the largest questionId and calculated percentages using a temp table.

Make sure you drop the temp tables after you are done printing the results. Hope this helps.

```
declare @questionId Integer
declare @maxQuestionId Integer
declare @countofAnswer Integer
declare @countofQuestion Integer
declare @percentofQuestionsAnswered decimal

set @questionId=1
set @maxQuestionId = (select max(questionId) from #temprecordset)

WHILE ( @questionId <= @maxQuestionId ) 
  BEGIN
  set @countofAnswer = (select sum(answer) from #temprecordset where QuestionId=@questionId)
  set @countofQuestion = (select count(*) from #temprecordset where QuestionId=@questionId)
  set @percentofQuestionsAnswered = @countofAnswer*100/@countofQuestion
  insert into #QuestionPercent values (@questionId,@percentofQuestionsAnswered)
  SET @questionId =@questionId + 1 
  END


  select * from #QuestionPercent
```

Comment: You should avoid loops in SQL and start thinking about sets

Comment: Yes. I try and avoid loops but the reason I used it here was in case there were more questions added. If there were 100 questions, it'll still work with a little tweaking in the select statement.

Comment: Still, you should avoid the loops; there is no need to compute _n_ times the aggregate functions

Comment: How do you do it with sets? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Coder77, just like the other answers